# Checkboxes, form submit, and how to use array_fill properly in a loop?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, forms, checkbox

I've got a form in which the user can make some changes to a grading scale. They also can select to apply those changes to 1 or more records (class section numbers).  Here is a screenshot of my form along with the code further below:

[image: Form Screenshot]

When I click the checkboxes, I need to insert the data from the form into the database using each of the section numbers from the checkboxes. Since the checkbox array holds only 3 values, it's not completing the insert of all the section number rows. In my code, you'll see that I tried using array_fill, but I'm clearly not using that correctly or in the right place.

This is what my database table correctly looks like before I submit my form: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/015a20/1

This is how the database table looks after I submit my form:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/15e40a/1

Here is my testing output of the variable giving me problems ($SectionNumber):

```
5011 is SectionNumber
5013 is SectionNumber
5099 is SectionNumber
is SectionNumber
is SectionNumber
is SectionNumber
is SectionNumber
is SectionNumber
is SectionNumber
is SectionNumber
is SectionNumber
is SectionNumber
is SectionNumber
is SectionNumber
5011 is SectionNumber
5013 is SectionNumber
5099 is SectionNumber
is SectionNumber
is SectionNumber
is SectionNumber
is SectionNumber
is SectionNumber
is SectionNumber
is SectionNumber
is SectionNumber
is SectionNumber
is SectionNumber
is SectionNumber
5011 is SectionNumber
5013 is SectionNumber
5099 is SectionNumber
is SectionNumber
is SectionNumber
is SectionNumber
is SectionNumber
is SectionNumber
is SectionNumber
is SectionNumber
is SectionNumber
is SectionNumber
is SectionNumber
is SectionNumber
```

I am needing/expecting the output to show "5011 is SectionNumber" repeated 11 times followed by "5013 is SectionNumber" and finally "5099 is SectionNumber" 11 times.

### HTML Form:

https://jsfiddle.net/keusv75a/

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post" name="snum">
   <p>
      Select the section for which you'd like to display the grading scale below:<br />
      <select name="snum">
         <?php
            $stmt4 = $connection->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT c.SectionNumber FROM Courses c, Assignments a WHERE a.SectionNumber = c.SectionNumber
            ") or die($connection->error);
            $stmt4->execute();
            $result4 = $stmt4->get_result();

            while ($row4 = $result4->fetch_assoc()):
            ?>
         <option value="<?php echo $row4['SectionNumber']; ?>" <?php
            if ($_POST['snum'] == $row4['SectionNumber']) {
                echo "selected";
            } ?>><?php echo $row4['SectionNumber']; ?></option>
         <?php
            endwhile; ?> 
      </select>
      <input class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" type="submit" value="Show Me">
   </p>
</form>
<form action="admin_grading_scale2.php" method="post">
   <p>Which section(s) would you like to apply this grading scale to?<br>
      <?php $stmt4 = $connection->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT SectionNumber FROM Courses
         ") or die($connection->error);
         $stmt4->execute();
         $result4 = $stmt4->get_result();

                      while ($row4 = $result4->fetch_assoc()):
         ?>
      <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="SectionNumber[]" value="<?=$row4['SectionNumber'];?>" id="SectionNumber[]"><?=$row4['SectionNumber'];?></label>
      <?php endwhile; ?>
   </p>
   <div class="form-inline">
   <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
         <tr class="table-text-center">
            <th scope="col"> Letter Grade</th>
            <th scope="col">Percent Toward Grade</th>
            <th scope="col">Avg Steps/Day</th>
            <th scope="col">Average Active Minutes/Week</th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         <?php
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $id = $row['id'];
            $letter = $row['letter'];
            $AssignmentID = $row['AssignmentID'];
            $percent = $row['percent'];
            $avgsteps = $row['avgsteps'];
            $avgweeklymin = $row['avgweeklymin'];
            $section = $row['section']; 
             ?>
         <input name="id[]" type="hidden" value="<?php echo "$id"; ?>"/>
         <input name="section[]" type="hidden" value="<?php echo "$section"; ?>"/>
         <input name="AssignmentID[]" type="hidden" value="<?php echo "$AssignmentID"; ?>"/>
         <tr class="table-text-center">
            <td>
               <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="letter" name="letter[]" aria-describedby="letter" placeholder="Grade" value="<?php echo "$letter"; ?>"> 
               </div>
            </td>
            <td>
               <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="percent" name="percent[]" aria-describedby="percent" placeholder="Percent" value="<?php echo "$percent"; ?>"> 
               </div>
            </td>
            <td>
               <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="avgsteps" name="avgsteps[]" aria-describedby="points" placeholder="Average Steps" value="<?php echo "$avgsteps"; ?>"> 
               </div>
            </td>
            <td>
               <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="avgweeklymin" name="avgweeklymin[]" aria-describedby="avgweeklymin" placeholder="Average Weekly Activity Minutes" value="<?php echo "$avgweeklymin"; ?>"> 
               </div>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <?php } ?>
      </tbody>
   </table>
   <input class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" value="Save Changes">
</form>
```

### PHP Code:

```
$size = count( $_POST[ 'id' ] );
$numofsections = count( $_POST[ 'SectionNumber' ] );

$stmt = $connection->prepare( "INSERT INTO GradingScale SET letter=?,percent=?,avgsteps=?,avgweeklymin=?,section=?,AssignmentID=? ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE letter=?,percent=?,avgsteps=?,avgweeklymin=?,section=?,AssignmentID=?" );

for($x = 0; $x < $numofsections; $x++):

    $SectionNumber = array_fill(0, $size, $_POST['SectionNumber'][$x]);

$i = 0;
while ( $i < $size ) {
    // define each variable 
    $id = filter_var( $_POST[ 'id' ][ $i ], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT );
    $letter = filter_var( $_POST[ 'letter' ][ $i ], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
    $percent = filter_var( $_POST[ 'percent' ][ $i ], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT );
    $avgsteps = filter_var( $_POST[ 'avgsteps' ][ $i ], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT );
    $avgweeklymin = filter_var( $_POST[ 'avgweeklymin' ][ $i ], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT );
    $AssignmentID = filter_var( $_POST[ 'AssignmentID' ][ $i ], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT );
    $SectionNumber = filter_var( $_POST[ 'SectionNumber' ][ $i ], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
    echo $SectionNumber .  "  is SectionNumber<BR>"; 

    $stmt->bind_param( "siiisisiiisi", $letter,$percent, $avgsteps, $avgweeklymin, $SectionNumber, $AssignmentID, $letter,$percent, $avgsteps, $avgweeklymin, $SectionNumber, $AssignmentID);
    $stmt->execute();

    //$stmt2->bind_param( "iii", $PointsPossible, $SectionNumber, $AssignmentID );
    //$stmt2->execute();

    ++$i;
}
endfor;
```

### Database Schema

```
CREATE TABLE `GradingScale` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `letter` enum('A','B','C','D','F') NOT NULL,
  `percent` smallint(4) NOT NULL,
  `avgsteps` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `avgweeklymin` smallint(4) NOT NULL,
  `section` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `AssignmentID` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='Grading Scale';


INSERT INTO `GradingScale` (`id`, `letter`, `percent`, `avgsteps`, `avgweeklymin`, `section`, `AssignmentID`) VALUES
(1, 'A', 100, 10000, 100, '5011', 1),
(2, 'A', 90, 9500, 90, '5011', 1),
(3, 'B', 80, 9000, 80, '5011', 1),
(4, 'C', 70, 8500, 70, '5011', 1),
(5, 'D', 60, 8000, 60, '5011', 1),
(6, 'F', 50, 7500, 50, '5011', 1),
(7, 'F', 40, 7000, 40, '5011', 1),
(8, 'F', 30, 6500, 30, '5011', 1),
(9, 'F', 20, 6000, 20, '5011', 1),
(10, 'F', 10, 5500, 10, '5011', 1),
(11, 'F', 0, 5000, 0, '5011', 1),
(12, 'A', 100, 10000, 100, '5013', 1),
(13, 'A', 90, 9500, 90, '5013', 1),
(14, 'B', 80, 9000, 80, '5013', 1),
(15, 'C', 70, 8500, 70, '5013', 1),
(16, 'D', 60, 8000, 60, '5013', 1),
(17, 'F', 50, 7500, 50, '5013', 1),
(18, 'F', 40, 7000, 40, '5013', 1),
(19, 'F', 30, 6500, 30, '5013', 1),
(20, 'F', 20, 6000, 20, '5013', 1),
(21, 'F', 10, 5500, 10, '5013', 1),
(22, 'F', 0, 5000, 0, '5013', 1),
(23, 'A', 100, 10000, 100, '5099', 1),
(24, 'A', 90, 9500, 90, '5099', 1),
(25, 'B', 80, 9000, 80, '5099', 1),
(26, 'C', 70, 8500, 70, '5099', 1),
(27, 'D', 60, 8000, 60, '5099', 1),
(28, 'F', 50, 7500, 50, '5099', 1),
(29, 'F', 40, 7000, 40, '5099', 1),
(30, 'F', 30, 6500, 30, '5099', 1),
(31, 'F', 20, 6000, 20, '5099', 1),
(32, 'F', 10, 5500, 10, '5099', 1),
(33, 'F', 0, 5000, 0, '5099', 1);

--
-- Indexes for table `GradingScale`
--
ALTER TABLE `GradingScale`
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`,`letter`,`percent`);

-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `GradingScale`
--
ALTER TABLE `GradingScale`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=34;
COMMIT;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assignment:

```
$SectionNumber = array_fill(0, $size, $_POST['SectionNumber'][$x]);
```

is being overwritten by this one:

```
$SectionNumber = filter_var( $_POST[ 'SectionNumber' ][ $i ], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
```

I think what you mean to do is:

```
$SectionNumbers = array_fill(0, $size, $_POST['SectionNumber'][$x]);
...
$SectionNumber = filter_var( $SectionNumbers[ $i ], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
```

Note addition of `$SectionNumbers` array to hold the values.

Comment: Thank you very much @Nick! That now generates the correct number of SectionNumbers. But now if I edit a value in the form, it does an insert for all of the fields instead of just the field I edited. I have a feeling the issue is the way I have defined my unique keys in the database but I'm not sure if that's it or not. Any ideas on that from you or anyone else?  Thanks again @Nick!

Comment: Hi Tim, I'm not sure exactly what you mean? Your code is written to insert all fields that are passed in $_POST, and it seems that that will include all the fields originally read from the table. If you want to only insert values which are changed, you will need to keep a copy of the old values so that you can compare against them to see if any value was changed.

Comment: I'm using ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE so shouldn't it update the current columns and insert the new? Or is that not an option based on my form submission scenario?

Comment: Hi Tim, I hadn't noticed the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE part of the query (too far out to the right! :). The reason that isn't working is that you have included `id` in the key, but `id` is an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column so it will get a new value on INSERT and never match. You should make `id` the PRIMARY key and have just `letter` and `percent` (and possibly `section`?) in the UNIQUE key.

Comment: Thanks Nick, I made those changes to the PRIMARY and UNIQUE keys. In my form, I changed the 100 percent to 95 percent. Instead of updating the row that previously had the 100 percent, it inserted a new row. Any other thoughts on this?

Comment: The problem is that by changing the percent value, you are changing the unique key. So it will always do an INSERT. This is tricky... My initial thought is the best way around it is to check the current SectionNumber against the one which was in the original form, and if it is the same, then include the id value in the insert. That will then cause a duplicate key error which will make the update happen instead. When the SectionNumber is not the same, don't include the id number on the insert (you should be able to set it to null I think)